# Email is bouncing off from few mail providers

Tags: email, smtp

when im trying to send email from my domain to polish email providers onet.pl and gazeta.pl im getting bounce back message:

```
     A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  XXX@gazeta.pl
    SMTP error from remote mail server after HELO mydomain.com:
    host mx.poczta.gazeta.pl [1.1.1.1]: 503 5.7.0 Error:
    access denied for unknown[2.2.2.2]
```

I have configured ptr and mx record. Please help.

Comment: Many be they detected that you are sending too many mails with the same from addr. Can you send the mail from an outside program outside of your SMTP logic.

Comment: Im not spamming from this domain, its just ecommerce website, and there was always that error for that domains, first email was bounced too.

Comment: Why does it say "access denied for unknown[2.2.2.2]"? What is unknown here?

Comment: I've only changed ip and domain name, and i really dont know why is unknown there.

Comment: Usually a SMTP transaction is HELO, MAIL FROM, RCPT TO and DATA. Have you performed all of them? You may be skipping the MAIL FROM as part of SMTP transaction.

Comment: Im sending email from prestashop, or rainloop so smtp transaction must be fine. And is i told every server except onet.pl and gazeta.pl is taking emails fine.

Comment: Test the email address at an online [email address validator](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/emailvalidator/) that does an smtp, does it pass?

Comment: It says "Address is valid", and successfully passes smtp connection test.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many possibilities for the mail denied. Please check :

1) Your mail server IP address should not be blacklisted anywhere. You can check it from http://multirbl.valli.org/lookup/

2) Make sure that the recipient mail server listen on the port which you are using i.e. Port 25. Please check if the port 587 works. You can also try port 465 with TLS.

3) Check if any Antivirus application installed on your side causes the issue.